# Is there a way to prevent VSBuild Jobs from clearing the bin directory?

Tags: c#, azure-devops

I am trying to create an Azure DevOps Pipeline that creates multiple C# binaries using multiple configurations.

It looks like the recommended way of doing this was by using multiple "Jobs", rather than multiple steps. Specifically I am using a matrix to specify, Debug|AnyCPU, Release|AnyCPU, Custom|AnyCPU.

This causes everything to build just fine. The problem is that each "Job" clears the bin directory, so at the end of the process, there is only one assembly in my bin directory.

I need all libraries in there. The goal is to create a NuGet package containing all the assemblies. I've considered using the Azure DevOps StagingArtifacts directory. I would just like to try to avoid having too many differences between building on a dev machine vs building on the build machine.

I am specifying separate output paths for each configuration. On my dev machine, I can batch build everything, and everything shows up in the bin directory.

```
strategy:
    matrix:
      debug-job:
        buildConfiguration: 'Debug'
      release-job:
        buildConfiguration: 'Release'
      custom-job:
        buildConfiguration: 'Custom'
```

```xml
<OutputPath Condition=" '$(OutputPath)' == '' ">bin\$(Configuration)\$(TargetFrameworkVersion)\</OutputPath>
```

Comment: Why not publish multiple sets of build artifacts, then create a release definition that generates and pushes the NuGet package from the sets of artifacts?

Comment: I guess I don't see a reason to store more artifacts than I need. The NuGet package will mostly be for internal use. Some internal customers will need all 3 assemblies, and others may just need 1. It seems like more maintenance to have several artifacts vs 1.

Additionally, if I am using intermediate artifacts, then the nuspec for the build machine will be different than what a developer could do on their dev machine. I'd like to avoid differences between dev and build machine configurations.

Comment: Why would the NuSpec need to be different? Your release definition would be responsible for grabbing the artifacts, "massaging" them into an appropriate folder structure, and packaging them up/pushing them to your artifacts feed.

Comment: So I am pretty new to creating nuspecs. Thinking about it, it looks like that actually could work pretty well. I could mimic the layout of the bin directory during the release pipeline, and then use a variable to resolve the beginning of the path. That would allow both dev and build machines to build NuGet packages.  

I guess I just need to figure out how to get the staging directory worked out. I assume I don't actually have to save my binaries to an artifact server. Is there any issue with just having a release pipeline rebuild those assemblies before I am ready to publish?

Comment: There's no need to rebuild in your release pipeline. There may be a slight terminology confusion here: "artifact" is an overloaded term. In the context of a build, it means **publish a build artifact** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops), which is associated with a build, *not* an artifacts feed.